# "expected primary-expression before ',' token" Can you find a mistake because i can't

Tags: arduino

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JIia.png)

code does not compile giving that expected primary-expression before ',' token mistake. I guess it is something obvious but i just can not find it
thanx

this is the code that should run a few stepper mottors
problem shows in the last line saying "expected primary-expression before ',' token"
Well i also want to know what type of mistake it is so i could solve that by myself in the future

```cpp
/* 
 *  
 */
//step
#define step_1 14
#define step_2 27
//direction
#define dir_1  12
#define dir_2  13
//buttons 
#define go_1 
#define go_2
#define go_3
#define go_4
//enable
#define enbl_1
#define enbl_2
//settings
#define rpms 100.0
#define steps_per_rev 100
#define m_per_s 1 /*microsteps per second */
#define m_per_m (1000000/(steps_per_rev * m_per_s)/(rpms / 60)) /* microseconds per microstep */

uint32_t last_step_time = 0;
uint32_t current_time = 0;
boolean stepping_1 = false;
boolean stepping_2 = false;

void setup() {

 //step
 pinMode(step_1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(step_2, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(step_1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(step_2, LOW);
 //dir
 pinMode(dir_1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(dir_2, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(dir_1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(dir_2, LOW);
 //enbl
 pinMode(enbl_1, INPUT);
 pinMode(enbl_2, INPUT);
 digitalWrite(enbl_1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(enbl_2, HIGH);
 //go
 pinMode(go_1, INPUT);
 pinMode(go_2, INPUT);
 pinMode(go_3, INPUT);
 pinMode(go_4, INPUT);

}


void loop() {

 stepping_1 = true;

 if (digitalRead(go_1) == LOW && stepping_1 == true)
 {
    current_time = micros(); // returns the time gone from the moment when the program has been runned
    if ((current_time - last_step_time) > m_per_m)
    {
      digitalWrite(enbl_1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(dir_1, LOW);
      last_step_time = current_time;
      digitalWrite(step_1, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds((m_per_m * 0.9)/2);
      digitalWrite(step_1, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds((m_per_m * 0.9)/2);
      digitalWrite(enbl_1, HIGH);
    }
  }


 if (digitalRead(go_2) == LOW && stepping_1 == true)
 {
    current_time = micros(); // returns the time gone from the moment when the program has been runned
    if ((current_time - last_step_time) > m_per_m)
    {
      digitalWrite(enbl_1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(dir_1, HIGH);
      last_step_time = current_time;
      digitalWrite(step_1, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds((m_per_m * 0.9)/2);
      digitalWrite(step_1, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds((m_per_m * 0.9)/2);
      digitalWrite(enbl_1, HIGH);
    }
  }

  if (digitalRead(go_3) == LOW && stepping_1 == true)
 {
    current_time = micros(); // returns the time gone from the moment when the program has been runned
    if ((current_time - last_step_time) > m_per_m)
    {
      digitalWrite(enbl_2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(dir_2, LOW);
      last_step_time = current_time;
      digitalWrite(step_2, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds((m_per_m * 0.9)/2);
      digitalWrite(step_2, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds((m_per_m * 0.9)/2);
      digitalWrite(enbl_2, HIGH);
    }
  }

  if (digitalRead(go_4) == LOW && stepping_1 == true)
 {
    current_time = micros(); // returns the time gone from the moment when the program has been runned
    if ((current_time - last_step_time) > m_per_m)
    {
      digitalWrite(enbl_2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(dir_2, HIGH);
      last_step_time = current_time;
      digitalWrite(step_2, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds((m_per_m * 0.9)/2);
      digitalWrite(step_2, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds((m_per_m * 0.9)/2);
      digitalWrite(enbl_2, HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here rather than a screenshot, thanks.

Comment: i uploaded my whole code/ screenshot is the last if in the code

Comment: There is no value attached to `#define enbl_2`, then `digitalWrite(enbl_2, HIGH);` becomes `digitalWrite(, HIGH);` after preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` statements have to have two parts--the alias/name, and what it is being defined as. If you don't have the second part, the preprocessor substitutes blank space for the name you defined. All the names below are improperly defined in your program:

```
#define go_1 
#define go_2
#define go_3
#define go_4
//enable
#define enbl_1
#define enbl_2
```

This leads to lines such as `pinMode(go_1, INPUT);` becoming `pinMode(, INPUT);` after preprocessing.

I would also highly recommend using all caps for your defines, as this will clearly differentiate them from real variables. This is important because a defined alias is replaced with a literal value, and thus cannot be modified.